# an adjective describing too simplistic a view

Tags: word-request, adjectives

I need an adjective that would describe a view on some matter of a person who didn't really bother to look deeper into it and, thus, are taking the matter in a very "flat" way, that is, not considering (or not ever being aware) of some important and even key details.

For example,

> "You have a very _____________ view on this matter. It was absolutely
>   not like the Prime Minister stepped down just because of that scandal.
>   There were many more factors involved and many more reasons played the
>   key role in his decision"

Comment: What’s wrong with using “simplistic” or one of its synonyms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could perhaps use the word "shallow" for this.

There's a clue to this in your "didn't really bother to look **deeper** into it".